# Range query using TiKV database

Tags: java, tikv

How do you do range query with TiKV and java-client?

Suppose I have this model:

```java
public class Hub implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private List<Schedule> schedules;
}
```

and

```java
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Schedule implements Serializable {
    private String day;
    private LocalTime opens; 
    private LocalTime closes;
}
```

How can I do a query that will satisfy this:

```java
new Schedule().builder()
    .day("Monday")
    .opens(LocalTime.parse("09:00")
    .close(LocalTime.parse("17:00").build();
```

1. How do you store the `Hub` model into TiKV
2. And, how can you do a range query to the `schedules` in this example?

Answer (score 2):

you can use client-java-client, see https://github.com/tikv/client-java

1. How do you store the Hub model into TiKV

if you want to use TiKV directly without TiDB, you can encode Hub into a ByteString and store the ByteString into TiKV.

https://github.com/tikv/client-java/blob/v3.0.0/src/main/java/org/tikv/raw/RawKVClient.java#L82

2. And, how can you do a range query to the schedules in this example?

you can use scan API to do a range query

https://github.com/tikv/client-java/blob/v3.0.0/src/main/java/org/tikv/raw/RawKVClient.java#L152

Please submit issues on https://github.com/tikv/client-java/issues if you have any questions or requests.

update at https://github.com/tikv/client-java/issues/105

Comment: Hi, if my model is serialized before storing how can this method `List<Kvrpcpb.KvPair> scan(ByteString startKey, ByteString endKey, int limit)` even query a child field? Can you provide a more concrete explanation?